# Apache 404 Error for url redirect for files in pub static folder

Tags: magento2, htaccess, apache

I am having problem with my setup in local and live, when I try to hit a url that dd not exist in : `pub/static/frontend/XXX/default/` folder it gives me apache 404 error. I have my alias or domain pointing to pub folder and my `htaccess` are fine.

I tried to hit this URL:

> dev.ndspro.com/static/version1525430192/frontend/Nds/default/en_US/images/stories/landingpage/pdf/EZflow_Manual_Web.pdf

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Nds/default/en_US/images/stories/landingpage/pdf/EZflow_Manual_Web.pdf'
#0 /home/devnds/public_html/releases/20181026112235/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(121): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /home/devnds/public_html/releases/20181026112235/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 /home/devnds/public_html/releases/20181026112235/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 try to create symlinks for some static resources when you are not in production mode. You can change that behavior like this:

- In `app/etc/di.xml`, section : `name="view_preprocessed"`, replace : `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` with : `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`.
- Remove the **content** of the bellow folders except `.htaccess`

  `var/view_preprocessed`, `pub/static`, `generated`
- Run :

  `php bin/magento c:c`, `php bin/magento c:f`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: is it good to make changes to di.xml directly..?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem for that, you can if you want do some backup before update it

Comment: it didn't solve the problem with domain pointing to pub file its working root folder. Can you suggest anything for pub folder.

Comment: can you please suggest.